# Reduce with async logic

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, reduce

In my reduce loop i'm trying to get two arrays from one.I have async logic inside iteration and I get an error as u can see because I've got promise in result on the third iteration and in broke my script. Here i attach my code to show how i do it!

```
const {
    readyScoreRequests,
    remainingScores,
  } = await scoreRequests.reduce(async (result, score) => {
    const { profile } = score;
    console.log('result', result);
    const importedScore = score.scoreId ? await importedScoreService.findOne({
      where: { id: score.scoreId },
    }) : null;
    const scoreDate = importedScore ? moment(importedScore.createdOn).format('MM/DD/YYYY') : 'New Score';

    const scoreInfo = {
      status: score.status.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + score.status.slice(1),
      scoreDate,
      name: profile ? profile.name : null,
      email: score.companyEmail ? score.companyEmail : null,
      city: profile ? profile.city : null,
      state: profile ? profile.state : null,
      logo: profile ? profile.logo : null,
    };

    if (score.status === 'ready') {
      result.readyScoreRequests.push(scoreInfo);
      return result;
    }

    result.remainingScores.push(scoreInfo);
    return result;
  }, { readyScoreRequests: [], remainingScores: [] });
```

[error in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNpWb.png)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Given that your reduce callback is async, the returned result is a promise. Notice how your log of `result` is a Promise. To successfully access the value from the previous iteration in the current, you must `await` that value first.

So instead of

```js
result.readyScoreRequests.push(scoreInfo)
```

You should await the result to get the inner value.

```js
const resultRes = await result
resultRes.readyScoreRequests.push(scoreInfo)
```

Here is a simplified example of this that should help to clarify:

```js
function multiply(value){
    return new Promise(res => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            res(value*2)
        }, 100)
    })
}

async function runSum(values){
    const sum = await values.reduce(async (acc, cur) => {
        const value = await multiply(cur)
        const accRes = await acc
        return accRes + value
    }, 0)
    console.log(sum)
}

runSum([1,2,3,4])
```

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted when the logic is sound? Even if the question itself is considered a duplicate, an answer is independent of that.